# Tag request: DigitalOcean

Tags: discussion, tags

[DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) is a very large VPS company, not unlike [Linode](http://linode.com).

Linode has a [tag](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linode) yet DigitalOcean does not. I'm sure that there are other people other than me wanting to ask questions about DigitalOcean.

Comment: It would not be unprecedented.   We have tags for some other large hosting companies such as [Tag:dreamhost], [Tag:godaddy], [Tag:amazon-aws] and [Tag:1and1]

Comment: Just because we don't have a tag, it doesn't mean you can ask the question.   Go ahead and ask.   You can tag the question with [tag:web-hosting] and [tag:vps] for now.

Comment: NB: Once you have 300 rep, you can create tags. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags